# unable to acces taskid of Celery task in helper fucntion of the same task?

Tags: python, celery, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to access taskid of celery task in different helper function with a AsyncResult but unable to acces it

https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult

iam a getting None on this link and Tried with some other links like https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html

```
def anotherFunction(data):
    try:
        fvlfn
    except Exception as identifier:
        logging.exception(identifier)


@app.task(bind=True)
def send(self):
    try:
        TASKID = self.request.id
        anotherFunction('no if s')
    except Exception as identifier:
        self.update_state(state='ALMOST DONE')
        logging.exception(self.request.id)
```

I want to access taskid in anotherFunction without passing it

Comment: ```app.current_task.request.id``` you will get current taskid in anywhere in program

Comment: I think you want to enable the Celery integration for Sentry instead of doing what you do. https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/celery/ That one will attach the task ID in "Additional Data" at the bottom of the event page.

Comment: it attaches task id , if the task is  called with get form the client. If we just give call the task and don't wait for response sentry addition data won't be containing taskId and we have to manully add task id , in filter function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the Celery application object to get the information about the current task: `myapp.current_task.request.id` (where myapp is an instance of the Celery class)

However, just because you can does not mean that is what you should do. Many of us prefer explicitly passing the data needed for function to run, instead of using some global object.